# Storage drive not seen by live media

Tags: live-usb, ssd, disk

I have previously installed an Ubuntu 16.04 partition on my laptops SSD but it became corrupted after a BIOS update so I want to reinstall. However when I boot from USB, Ubuntu can't see the SSD. `fdisk -l` lists the USB itself and my RAM but not the SSD.

However I know the disk is ok because I can still boot in to my Windows 10 partition. What has made the disk unreadable to the live USB?

EDIT: I've run my GParted live USB to check if that works and it spits out these errors

`ACPI Error: [...] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND
 ACPI Exception: AE_NOT_FOUND
 ACPI Error: 1 table load failures, 12 successful`

Comment: what do you mean corrupted? do you mean the bios update overwrote the grub boot? I've had this happen.

Comment: Ok so I said that to avoid telling the painful story. The Cliffs Notes version is that the BIOS update resulted in needing to update Nvidia drivers. However, after booting ubuntu the graphic driver would crash before I could update them so I had to force power off several times. After doing this something in grub2 is very unhappy and I think its easier to reinstall than to try and fix grub2. Lessons have been learned!

Comment: ah, yes sounds like the forced power off corrupted something. grub can be asily reinstalled but there may be other errors now. as far as not seeing the SSD, be sure the USB is booting in the same mode as windows (UEFI vs Legacy/BIOS)

Comment: They are both definitely booting in UEFI and I still have this issue. (Legacy is disabled).

Comment: secure boot off? secure boot will prevent grub from loading modules it needs

Comment: yep, secure boot is off.